# What is the syntax for a cURL command in the python for GCP Composer (airflow) bash_command

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, command, google-cloud-composer

Below is my code where I am trying to use GCP composer to submit a job via a cURL command.
I get a "bash command failed" error message.
What is wrong with the bash_command= line?
This command works from command line and from within a bash script, but fails when plugging in to the GCP Composer example python code. Maybe escaping some characters?

Thx.

Here is the full log:
`*** Reading remote log from gs://us-east1-dataclymer-airflow-9312ee93-bucket/logs/gcp_composer_airflow_matillion/gcp_composer_airflow_matillion/2020-02-04T19:22:58.964822+00:00/1.log.
[2020-02-04 19:23:05,032] {**init**.py:1189} INFO - Dependencies all met for 
[2020-02-04 19:23:05,041] {**init**.py:1189} INFO - Dependencies all met for

### [2020-02-04 19:23:05,041] {**init**.py:1403} INFO -

[2020-02-04 19:23:05,041] {**init**.py:1404} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2

### [2020-02-04 19:23:05,041] {**init**.py:1405} INFO -

[2020-02-04 19:23:05,079] {**init**.py:1424} INFO - Executing  on 2020-02-04T19:22:58.964822+00:00
[2020-02-04 19:23:05,080] {base_task_runner.py:119} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'gcp_composer_airflow_matillion', 'gcp_composer_airflow_matillion', '2020-02-04T19:22:58.964822+00:00', '--job_id', '3345', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/gcp_composer_airflow_matillion.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpcvqzg0n4']
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,032] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/configuration.py:569: DeprecationWarning: Specifying both AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and airflow_home in the config file is deprecated. Please use only the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and remove the config file entry.
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,032] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,544] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,543] {settings.py:185} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, pid=95352
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,710] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,709] {default_celery.py:90} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,712] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,712] {**init**.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,919] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,919] {app.py:54} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,924] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,923] {configuration.py:556} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,927] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/configuration.py:569: DeprecationWarning: Specifying both AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and airflow_home in the config file is deprecated. Please use only the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and remove the config file entry.
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,927] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-02-04 19:23:06,930] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:06,930] {settings.py:185} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, pid=95352
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,013] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,012] {**init**.py:596} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/gcp_composer_airflow_matillion.py
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,691] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,691] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running  on host airflow-worker-75bc494cb4-m4jdz
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,746] {bash_operator.py:82} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion  /tmp
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {bash_operator.py:91} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=gcp_composer_airflow_matillion
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=gcp_composer_airflow_matillion
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2020-02-04T19:22:58.964822+00:00
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2020-02-04T19:22:58.964822+00:00
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp2o6y6l8q/gcp_composer_airflow_matillionss6e394n
[2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:07,747] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: curl -s -u 'ec2-user:i-0d44f430cf31cb57b' -X POST 'http://52.13.147.192/rest/v0/tasks?groupName=sf-giants&projectName=Development&versionName=default&environmentName=Development&jobName=test_bash_time'
[2020-02-04 19:23:08,021] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:23:08,021] {bash_operator.py:124} INFO - Output:
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,780] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:25:18,778] {bash_operator.py:132} INFO - Command exited with return code 7
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,798] {**init**.py:1631} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/**init**.py", line 1491, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 136, in execut
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed"
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command faile
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:25:18,798] {**init**.py:1631} ERROR - Bash command failed
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {**init**.py:1654} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/**init**.py", line 1491, in _run_raw_task
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 136, in execute
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-04 19:25:18,821] {**init**.py:1654} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,854] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,855] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in 
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,855] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     exec(compile(f.read(), **file**, 'exec'))
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,855] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 32, in 
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,856] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     args.func(args)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,856] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,856] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,857] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 523, in run
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,857] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,857] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 442, in _run
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,858] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     pool=args.pool,
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,858] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,858] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,859] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/**init**.py", line 1491, in _run_raw_task
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,859] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,863] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 136, in execute
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,863] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion     raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
[2020-02-04 19:25:18,863] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3345: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
`

````
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'gcp_composer_airflow_matillion',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='gcp composer airflow matillion dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))

# priority_weight has type int in Airflow DB, uses the maximum.
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='gcp_composer_airflow_matillion',
    bash_command='curl -s -u "ec2-user:i-xxxxx" -X POST "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/rest/v0/tasks?groupName=xx-xxx&projectName=Development&versionName=default&environmentName=Development&jobName=test_bash_time"',
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    priority_weight=2**31-1)```
````

Comment: Execute the command manually and review the error message.

Comment: Thanks John,
 I have run from cmd line and from bash script (and mentioned this in my write-up!). Appreciate you responding!

Comment: My comment was run it manually from the command line and review the error message. What is the error message?

Comment: Have you tried to run any other simple working command and see if the error persists?

Comment: Error message:

{__init__.py:1631} ERROR - Bash command failed

I can take the text directly from the log file and run it from cmd line:

[2020-02-03 20:33:56,205] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2936: Subtask gcp_composer_airflow_matillion [2020-02-03 20:33:56,205] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: curl -s -u 'xx-xxxxx:kjhdgfjhgfj' -X POST 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx.192/rest/v0/tasks?groupName=sf-giants&projectName=Development&versionName=default&environmentName=Development&jobName=test_bash_time'

Comment: Albert: yes, I have run a simple 'echo test' from same code replacing the bash_command that fails.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the context? Is the following right?

-You have a python file with only the code you copy pasted
-You uploaded that python file to the DAG files bucket of your environment
-After some time, the DAG you created shows an error message stating that?

I have noticed that there should be some more code or other dependency errors would arise, given that you are using "airflow" method [airflow.utils...] without importing it (you are only importing DAG and BashOperator but not airflow itself).

Comment: Have you considered just using the configuration code proposed in the quickstart?

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#creating_a_dag

Comment: I've added the full log file above.
I took the example code from elsewhere in my GCP environment provided by google (i suspect). I took working python that has a simple 'echo test' as it's bash command and thought i could replace it with another working bash command (cURL).

I'll try the quickstart example next, appreciate you hanging in here w/me.

I'll try the "quickstart